# Python decryption not matching .NET encryption

Tags: c#, python, .net, cryptography, pycrypto

Python Encryption:

```
salt = 16 * b'\0'
keyIV = PBKDF2(Config.SECRET, salt).read(48)
key = keyIV[:32]
iv = keyIV[-16:]
aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

# padding
length = 16 - (len(textToEncrypt) % 16)
print(len(textToEncrypt))
textToEncrypt += length * b'\0'

encrypted = aes.encrypt(textToEncrypt)
encoded = base64.b64encode(encrypted)
return encoded
```

And here is my C# decryption:

```
        textToDecrypt = textToDecrypt.Replace(" ", "+");
        byte[] bytesToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(textToDecrypt);
        string decryptedText;
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            byte[] salt = new byte[16];
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes crypto = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Config.SECRET, salt);
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Key = crypto.GetBytes(32);
            aes.IV = crypto.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream(mStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cStream.Write(bytesToDecrypt, 0, bytesToDecrypt.Length);
                }
                decryptedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(mStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return decryptedText;
```

**EDIT**

Following @kelalaka answer, I'm now able to encrypt from C# and decrypt that string in python successfully, but not vice versa. That is, if I encrypt a string in python, and try to decrypt that encryption in C# I get an exception: "Bad PKCS7 padding. Invalid length 0". My python encryption is much shorter than what I get in C# using the same cipherText, iv, and key.

Comment: Your IV is incorrect in Python that makes the first block garbage. You need to call `PBKDF2(Config.SECRET, salt).read(48)` and divide it. Actually, it is better if you prepend the IV to the ciphertext as a usual practice. Why do you use CBC?

Comment: What do you mean by divide it? When I change the read it says the IV has to be 16 bytes. I'm new to cryptography, I'm using CBC because that's why I found in the example I'm following. I have tried CFB but get similar results.

Comment: In C# the successive call to GetBytes will give you new values. In python, the key's first 16 byte will be the same as IV. Generate 48 bit, take 32 as key and rest as IV. Normally, the IV sent together with the ciphertext without encryption. Concantrate in modern mode of operations like AES-GCM.

Comment: Dividing it solved the issue. Thanks for explaining that to me!

Comment: Write your answer?

Comment: @nblandfo: CBC mode has various security problems, if you have any choice you should not use it these days. Suggested alternative would be AES-GCM

Comment: Unfortunately Xamarin.ios doesn't support GCM yet. I've gotten closer but still having issues, edited above